# Cant update vertex property with Cardinality.list in Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I use tinkergraph-gremlin and gremlin-core, version  3.4.5. Also i use janusgraph.

I create a property with Cardinality.list by managment

And if i add a new Vertex with cardinality.list property, it works

```
    traversal().V()
               .hasLabel("Person")
               .property(VertexProperty.Cardinality.list, "History", "123")
               .property(VertexProperty.Cardinality.list, "History", "12")
               .iterate();
```

But if i gonna update the same vertex

```
    traversal().V("some_vertex_id")
               .property(VertexProperty.Cardinality.list, "History", "1")
               .iterate();
```

I got an Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple properties exist for the provided key, use 
Vertex.properties(History)
```

I cant understand why i got it

I read documentation and search for answers in stackoverflow, but it looks like a bug

Comment: is this a "tinkergraph" question or a "janusgraph" question? your question description mentions "tinkergraph-gremlin-core" (not an available artifact - either `gremlin-core` or `tinkergraph-gremlin`) but you've tagged the question as "janusgraph". fwiw, 3.4.5 TinkerGraph seems to work fine for me when I test multi-properties. Perhaps you need to clarify your question a bit further?

Comment: I use tinkergraph-gremlin and gremlin-core, version  3.4.5. Also i use janusgraph. I dont know what you mean, to choose "tinkergraph" question or a "janusgraph" question, i use both of them. I edit my question, there was some mistakes

Comment: It's important to know in which graph you see this error occurring. All TinkerPop-enabled databases have different implementations so a problem for one may not be a problem for another. As I've already explained, I don't seem to be able to recreate your problem with TinkerGraph at all, but have not tested JanusGraph so perhaps the problem is only there. I'd recommend you clarify which graph you see as having the problem and then include the text from a fully failing Gremlin Console session. That should make the problem easy to recreate.

Comment: it is in Janusgraph

i found pull request here

https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/1972

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It a bug of Janusgraph

Must be resolved in pull request

https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/1972